# Json Value with "native" keyword accept in java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In Java as we now `native` is keyword so we can not used this as a field.
but in currently working project I have json with the field name `native`. How do I use this field in my pojo class related to the native `json`.

Comment: Try annotating your field, or its getter and setter methods, with `@JsonProperty("native")` .

Answer (score 0):

For Jackson, use [`@JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) to indicate the property name used for (de)serialization:

```
@JsonProperty("native")
private String nativeValue;
```